# Alter the filter on autocomplete to allow sorting on complete string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a functioning autocomplete jQuery input control but there are two things it is doing that I would like to alter.

First, it fires again and again.  I would like for the data to be returned once, cached and not called again.

Second, I would like for the user to type in the control and based on what they type be able to search the entire string and not just the beginning.

This is my functioning script that returns data to the autocomplete and WORKS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "FacilitiesAsync",
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                data: 'sourceDb=myDb',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    // call autocomplete callback method with results 
                    response($.map(json, function (name) {
                        return {
                            label: name.label,
                            value: name.value
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#autocomplete").text(textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#autocomplete').val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

I found this bit of code that overrides the filter feature of the autocomplete but I have NO IDEA where to add this.  I have tried several places to no avail....

```
// Overrides the default autocomplete filter function to search only from the beginning of the string
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
    return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
  });
};
```

My input control looks like this.

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
```

I appreciate the direction...

Answer (score 0):

To cache the data from your server, setup a separate function which handles (and caches, if necessary) the response from your ajax call:

```
var cachedResult = null;
function fetchResponse(callback) {
    if (cachedResult) callback(cachedResult)
    $.ajax({
        url: "FacilitiesAsync",
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        data: 'sourceDb=myDb',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            // call autocomplete callback method with results 
            var cachedResult = $.map(json, function (name) {
                return {
                    label: name.label,
                    value: name.value
                };
            });
            callback(cachedResult);
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#autocomplete").text(textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            fetchResponse(function(result) {
                response(result)
            })
        }
    });
});
```

As for the custom matcher, look no further than the docs, in the [Using a custom source callback to match only the beginning of terms](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1) example.  Your custom matcher only differs in the regex pattern.  Note also that this is all done within the "source" callback.

Comment: your code works the same as mine.  The call is made each time the user enters a third character to tries to backspace to enter new search criteria.  Is there a setting that I can chage to make this cached?  Obviously, the cache property is set to "true" so one would think that would do it.